# Не работает UPDATE. Как быть?

Tags: php, mysql

Всем доброго времени суток.
Понадобился код-счетчик посещений. Нашел в интернете туториал, но вот код почему-то не работает.

Вот SQL

```html
CREATE TABLE `pageview` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `page` text NOT NULL,
 `userip` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


// totalview

CREATE TABLE `totalview` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `page` text NOT NULL,
 `totalvisit` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

```html
<?php
  $host="localhost";
  $username="root";
  $password="";
  $databasename="sample";

  $connect=mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
  $db=mysql_select_db($databasename);

  // gets the user IP Address
  $user_ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

  $check_ip = mysql_query("select userip from pageview where page='yourpage' and userip='$user_ip'");
  if(mysql_num_rows($check_ip)>=1)
  {
 
  }
  else
  {
    $insertview = mysql_query("insert into pageview values('','yourpage','$user_ip')");
 $updateview = mysql_query("update totalview set totalvisit = totalvisit+1 where page='yourpage' ");
  }
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <?php
    $stmt = mysql_query("select totalvisit from totalview where page='yourpage' ");
  ?>

  <p>This page is viewed <?php echo mysql_num_rows($stmt);?> times.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Любое посещение в таблице "pageview" отмечается. И добавляет все как надо. Однако не суммирует уникальные посещения почему-то в таблице "totalview". Вообще глухо.

Уже как только не перепробовал, и отдельно создавал чисто пустую страницу под туториаловский код. Сетовал на то, что мог мой код как-то конфликтовать. Без изменений.

Думал даже почистить куки, поскольку говорили, что может быть проблема в этом, но нет.

Что скажете?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А почему поле totalvisit, по всем прикидкам число, имеет тип TEXT? Да и userip тоже... *Думал даже почистить куки, поскольку говорили, что может быть проблема в этом* Больше НИКОГДА не слушай того, кто это сказал. *Что скажете?* Включи General log и проверяй, в каком виде добрался до сервера запрос.

Comment: Вы делаете `update` таблицы `totalview`. А запись там есть, которую Вы обновляете?.. `SELECT * FROM totalview WHERE page='yourpage'` - результат - одна строка ровно?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю у вас тут ошибка:

```
$updateview = mysql_query("update totalview set totalvisit = totalvisit+1 where page='yourpage' ");
```

Нужно, разбить на два запроса:

> 1. Выбрать totalview

```
 $totalview = mysql_num_rows(
  mysql_query(
   "select totalvisit from totalview where page='yourpage'"
 )
)
```

> 2. Добавить 1 вход пользователя

```
$totalview++;
```

> 3. Обновить поле в таблице.

```
mysql_query("update totalview set $totalvisit where page='yourpage' ")
```

Comment: Господи, нет, никогда так не делайте и никому не рассказывайте, пожалуйста. И тому кто Вас так научил делать - дайте в лицо, вот честно. Ну или если он больше и сильнее Вас - то лучше просто забыть. К слову, Вы только что предложили вместо одного красивого mysql запроса сделать два (!) просто так.